re.finditer find one pattern of multiple matches in a text file
I want to search for a pattern in text files and send the file where the match is found.
Using re.finditer because I have two matching lists (patterns and names of the files to email)
I want to send one file even if there are multiple matches.
Is this possible?

file1:
thre pat1 patterns 
pat1 
pat1 
file2:
Only one pat2 
bla bla 
import re
import itertools

cc_files = ["file1", "file2"] 
patlist = ["pat1", "pat2"]
prglist = ["prg1", "prg2"]

for (a, b) in itertools.zip_longest(patlist, prglist):
    for cc_file in cc_files:
        for i, line in enumerate(open(cc_file)):
            for match in re.finditer(a, line):
                print('Found on line %s: %s in file %s' % (i+1, match.group(), cc_file))
                # email: filename=(b + "_" + cc_file)) </code>`

output:
Found on line 1: pat1 in file file1 
Found on line 2: pat1 in file file1 
Found on line 3: pat1 in file file1 
Found on line 1: pat2 in file file2 
I want: 
pat1 in file1 
pat2 in file2 

Then why would you use finditer instead of just find?  If find returns something, you print the line and break to do the next line.

What I would like to find one match and go to the next pattern search.

Why does your code print the line where the pattern was found if your desired output doesn't need the line number?

Good question. For information; I though it wil not hurt.

Maybe I should clarify. Text files are close caption transcripts. Based on a words pattern the script will recognize the program and email the file with the proper program name. So if there are more than one matches in the file I do not want to send the same file multiple times.

The OUTERMOST loop should be the file names.  Open the file and read the entire contents -- don't do it line by line.  Now you can just do if pat in filetext: for each pattern, and if found, break to do the next file.

I don't think you need anything more complicated than this:
cc_files = ["file1", "file2"] 
patlist = ["pat1", "pat2"]
prglist = ["prg1", "prg2"]

for cc_file in cc_files:
    text = open(cc_file).read()
    for (a, b) in zip(patlist, prglist):
        if a in text:
            print("File", cc_file, "is program", b)
            break

I'm not sure why you used zip_longest.  If either of the two lists ends early, what can you possibly do with the rest?
If you need line numbers, then it gets a little more complicated, but not much.

No need for line number. That is perfect and simple, elegant.
